# How can I generate and install runtime dependencies with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I use CMake to build the project "Proj" and then install it.

Now I want to install two runtime dependencies (extra1.bin, extra2.bin) together with Proj, into the same directory.

The bin files are generated from the input file extra.json. I want the bin files to be regenerated when extra.json changes (not very often).

Relevant parts of my CMakeLists.txt look like this:

```
project(Proj)

add_library(Proj SHARED main.cpp)

set(EXTRA_FILES extra1.bin extra2.bin)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${EXTRA_FILES}
    COMMAND generate-extra-files extra.json
    DEPENDS extra.json
    VERBATIM
)

install(TARGETS Proj COMPONENT main_component)
```

How do I accomplish what I want?

1. I tried adding the bin files as dependencies for Proj, but then CMake expects them to exist when I generate the make files and a change in extra.json does not trigger a rebuild.
2. I tried using `add_custom_target(ExtraTarget ${EXTRA_FILES))`, but then the files are always regenerated.
3. I can't figure out how to use `install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS ...` and if it solves my problem.

It seems that I might have messed up the paths of my `EXTRA_FILES` in option 1, and maybe it does work is I want it to.

Comment: are these extra files executables/libraries? Or are they just data? In any case, why not use [`install(FILES|PROGRAMS ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#files)?

Comment: They are data. Right now I'm letting my library depend on them and have also added an install().

Comment: so does `install(FILES)` solve your problem? I'm confused.

Comment: Well, by using `target_sources(Proj PRIVATE ${EXTRA_FILES})` together with `install(DIRECTORY ${DIRECTORY_WITH_EXTRA_FILES} ....)`. I guess that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install files with [`install(FILES ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#files), and directories with [`install(DIRECTORY ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#directory).